# Who initialize a char pointer inside a struct on the stack

Tags: c, pointers, nullpointerexception

Its generally known that things on the stack are not initialized by default. I tried to prove that with a struct on the stack, but unexpectedly my pointer is initialized with null, but why? What is initializing this pointer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct strustri {
    int var1;
    char *var2;
};

int main()
{
    struct strustri test1 = {
            .var1 = 12,
            .var2 = "Teststring",
    };
    struct strustri test2;

    printf("test1.var1 is %d\n", test1.var1);
    printf("test2.var1 is %d\n", test2.var1);

    printf("test1.var2 points to %p\n", test1.var2);
    printf("test2.var2 points to %p\n", test2.var2);
    return 1;
}
```

And this is the output on my machine (Ubuntu 12.10):

```
test1.var1 is 12
test2.var1 is -1271814320
test1.var2 points to 0x400634
test2.var2 points to (nil)
```

I ran my example multiple times. I get another value for var1 everytime, but var2 is always points to zero (null pointer)...

Comment: You know, even a stopped clock shows correct time twice every day.

Comment: Yes, but I ran the program several times. All the other addresses shuffled, so I thought its highly unlikely that it's always nil by chance...

Comment: Undefined behaviour might just surprise you on occasions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is initializing it.

It's just an artefact of whatever rubbish happens to be on your stack.  Switch the order of the variable declarations, or add some more local variables, and you'll get a different result.

Comment: You are right. As soon as I switched the order, the pointer points to rubbish on every run of the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your test structures in a separate function, then have another function that creates an array of char, say 200 bytes long, that you fill with some letters, and call the two functions alternating, you'll notice that your values in test2 will be different [most likely, but not 100% guaranteed - since we are dealing with "undefined behaviour", something else could happen].

Answer (score 0):

when int var1 is executed to create space for test2, it has create space for itself but if you don't assign a value to it then it will show the value which was already there..

but in case of var2, it is a pointer. if pointers are not initialized then it does not point to anything, making it nil or NULL or '\0'

Comment: Yes but since a pointer on the stack is not initialized by default, it *should* point to a random address... That is what I expected...